# Difference between また明日 and では明日?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

I understand what 明日{あした} means. And I understand また明日 means "see you tomorrow". But I recently heard では明日, and I do not understand what it means/the difference between また明日.

また明日 translates to "In addition tomorrow".

では明日 translates to "So tomorrow".

I used http://www.systranet.com/translate/ to translate.

Clarification and understanding would be helpful.

I'm trying to learn Japanese.

Comment: You can also say 「では、また明日。」:D

Comment: @choco I think that confused me more. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imagine a sequel to the these expressions, like a whole sentence for example :

> また明日話を続けましょう。 : Let's continue our talk again tomorrow.
>
> では明日話を続けましょう。 : So let's continue our talk tomorrow.

I think when you are in a hurry the second one is a bit better, a conversation for example :

> 私 : あっ、そろそろ帰らないと親に殺される！ : Ah! If I don't get back soon I'll get killed by my parents!
>
> 友達 : 待ってよ！明日はどうする？ : Wait a sec! How do we do for tomorrow?
>
> 私 : うーん、お前は飲み物持ってきて！俺が食料とか買うんだから。 : Hum, You bring the drinks! Coz I'll get the food and other stuffs.
>
> 私 : あっ、じゃ明日！ : See ya!

Here I don't feel like the 「また明日」 would be better. But that is only my way of seeing things, if a native speaker could confirm it would be nice.